# Referencing color as named vector in Inline CSS in Quarto

Tags: css, r, quarto

I am playing around with Quarto and really like it. One feature is to change the color of inline text with the following below syntax (the word chemical will show up in red color)

```
[chemical]{style="color: red"}
```

My question is how to change the color of the text if we assign a color to name rather than the color code or built in color code? The below will not work

```
var="#28A569"
[chemical]{style="color: var"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure whether Quarto offers a more straightforward approach. But one option would be to use some inline code or following the [R Markdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/font-color.html#using-an-r-function-to-write-raw-html-or-latex-code) use a small custom function.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
---

[chemical]{style="color: #28A569"}

```{r, echo=FALSE}
var <- "#28A569"
```

`r sprintf('[chemical]{style="color: %s"}', var)`

```{r}
colorize <- function(x, color) {
  sprintf('[%s]{style="color: %s"}', x, color)
}
```

`r colorize("chemical", var)`
````

[image]

Comment: I think, using css variable is an easier option than defining a R function to do this.

Comment: @shafee I already guessed that this is possible using CSS variables and perhaps `bslib` also offers some more straightforward options too. But IMHO what's easier depends on the use case and is also a matter of taste. For me writing a small R function is quite often the more natural way and quick and easy approach. Especially if things get more complicated, e.g. consider the case where you want both the option to set the font and background color. This could be easily added in my function approach using e.g. an `fg` and `bg` argument but involves a lot of typing in your approach.

Answer (score 2):

An easy option would be to do this using [CSS variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties#basic_usage).

````
---
title: CSS variable in Inline Style
format: html
engine: knitr
---

```{css, echo=FALSE}
:root {
  --color1: #28A569;
  --color2: yellow;
}
```


[chemical]{style="color: var(--color1);"}

[This has colored background]{style="background-color: var(--color1);"}

[This has yellow background]{style="background-color: var(--color2);"}
````

---

[image]

---

Comment: awesome! still trying to learn css this is really helpful